# Nivo-slider shows 2 images at once and one is shrinked in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, drupal-7, nivo-slider

I am building a website in Drupal 7. I used the module nivo-slider and the nivo-slider plugin. The slideshow looks good everywhere except in IE8. The website has to work great in IE8. In IE8, it is showing two images at the same time and one of the image is all shrinked on the left.

The slideshow has to be full browser-width, here is the css code to make the slideshow full browser width:

```
    #page {
  max-width: 100%;
}
    #main-content {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

I googled a lot this issue but was not able to find the exact issue explained by someone else. I also tried different solutions with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without a demo of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If ever someone will face the same issue, here is how it fixed it for me:

```
 #page{
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this will help someone else.